# What does ' !!window.google ' mean?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

I'm reading through https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/using-the-google-maps-api-with-vue/ . In the section in the screenshot the author uses:

```
let initialized = !!window.google;
```

What does this mean?

Comment: In this case wouldn't it just be checking if there's a `google` value saved on the `window` object and converting it to a boolean using the double `!!`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`window.google` either evaluates to *something*, or it evaluates to `undefined`.

Before we get to your question, we need to look at the concept of ["truthiness"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered  true when encountered in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN

Okay, back to your question. Let us assume it is something (a truthy value).  `!something` will evaluate to false.  `!false` evaluates to true, so `!!something` will evaluate to true.

Assume now that it is `undefined`.  In this case `!undefined` evaluates to true, then `!true` evaluates to false.  So, `!!undefined` will evaluate to false.

In other words: **if it is something (truthy), it is initialized.  If not, then it hasn't been initialized.**

So, `!` before a truthy value (*something*) will make it false, then the extra `!` negates that.  Truthy things become true, and falsy things become false.

Comment: whats the difference between `if (!!something)` and  `if (something)`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Generally nothing. You only use double negative if you want to *return* that value or use it somewhere else. For logical comparisons it's pointless. Note in the question this is being assigned to a variable. `!!` means "I don't care what the value is, just if it's logically true or false".

Comment: @tadman makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I think of it as "flattening" a truthy/falsy value to true or false.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine That would throw that error.  Member access has a higher [order of precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than logical not.

Comment: @Amy yup haha just tested it and realized that was not the case.

Answer (score 3):

!! is a shorthand way of converting a variable into Boolean value. If google script is loaded correctly, `window.google` would exist as an `object`. `!object` would return `false` (if it is legit value, it is converted to true in Boolean checks in js, object is evaluated as `true`, `!true` is `false`). Second not operating converts the `false` back to `true`, so object is converted into a Boolean value.

Same way, if there was error loading the script, then `window.google` would be 'undefined', which is evaluated to be `false`. using double not operating you convert `undefined` into actual Boolean value `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`!!expression` is a terse idiom to cast an expression's value to a Boolean.

In this case, `initialized` will be set to `true` or `false` based on whether there's a global `google` property with a truthy value.